# Error: Metadata version mismatch for module @ionic-native/core/decorators.d.ts

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I can build my ionic project with `ionic cordova build ios` but when I build with `--release --prod` options I got this error :

```
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module 

node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
```

I know it's a @ionic-native plugins version issue but I cannot fix it. I found a lot of git issues or forum but no one have the same versions as me.

Here are my dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.7",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.1.10",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-analytics": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/vibration": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "@types/stripe": "^3.0.0",
    "ajv": "^5.5.2",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "1.1.1",
    "angular2-swiper": "^0.8.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.0",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-app-event": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "^0.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^0.14.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-vibration": "^2.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.3",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^0.3.7",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.2.1",
    "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": "^0.8.5",
    "dropbox": "^2.5.7",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "firebase": "^4.3.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-image-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic3-calendar": "git+https://github.com/ReaperSoon/ionic3-calendar.git",
    "ionicons": "4.4.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "localforage-cordovasqlitedriver": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-imgcache": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-simple-timer": "^1.3.5",
    "promise-polyfill": "6.0.2",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
    "stripe": "^4.25.0",
    "superagent": "^3.7.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.9",
    "in-app-purchase": "^1.10.6",
    "typescript": "2.4.0"
},
```

Can anyone help me to find what's wrong with my dependencies versions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same problem... Did you solved?

Comment: @victor Hi, I solved it but I cannot not remember how... I tried a lot of versions until it works fine and never changed the versions again ^^

Comment: @victor, try to compare your dependencies versions with mine : https://pastebin.com/Mx186ihS hope it will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to update all plugins from ionic to the latest
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-check-plugins

Install it globally:

```
$ npm install -g cordova-check-plugins
```

Then run from the root of your Cordova project. You can optionally update outdated plugins interactively or automatically, e.g.

```
$ cordova-check-plugins --update=auto
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it not works after updates :/ I have this https://pastebin.com/aUfKzWQ5

Comment: remove and install those 2 plugins again

Answer (score 0):

Your `@ionic-native/core` version of `^4.17` expects Angular 5, but you've listed dependencies for Angular 4 (`^4.4.7`).

You can upgrade to `"ionic-angular": "3.9.8"` and `"@angular/core": "5.2.11"`

Remember to update the other angular dependencies to the same version as well (@angular/common, @angular/compiler, etc.)

Note: Some of your other dependencies that rely on angular v4 might also need to be upgraded.